# ¿Como obtener subString sin interferir con otra subString?

Tags: php

Mi problema requiero poder extraer de un `string` una **subString** sin interferir o tomar contenido de lo que vendría siendo otra **subString**, conociendo el valor medio de cada **subString**. Me explico debo poder de un mensaje extraer una cantidad, un producto y una especificación. **Ejemplo:**

> cuatro camionetas de color rojo, cinco carros de maleta compacta y una moto de color rojo ultra rápida.

De este mensaje o oración debo poder extraer la **cantidad** y **especificación** de cada producto en una cadena individual para cada producto, conociendo el producto. Por ahora tengo este **código** representativo.

```
$mess='cuatro camionetas de color rojo, cinco carros de maleta compacta y una moto de color rojo ultra rápida.';
$mess=str_replace('y', ',', $mess);
$mess=str_replace('e', ',', $mess);
$mess=str_replace('.', '', $mess);

$array=explode(',',$mess);
foreach($array as $subString){
   print $subString;
   $array2=explode('carro',$subString);
   var_dump($array2);

}
```

Con este código de ejemplo limpio **eliminando** el punto final del mensaje y remplazo los caracteres conectores (y-e) con comas (,) para luego separar la `string` en **subString** para luego cada una de estas dividirlas en 2 conociendo el valor del medio que en este caso seria carro, gracias a que poseen un valor que las separa en subString (,) puedo separarlas de una manera que no tome contenido de la otra **subString**, es decir, no produce que por error al tomar la especificación del primer producto, también se lleve la cantidad del segundo, Por supuesto esto solo me permitirá obtener la la cantidad y especificación de la **subString** que contiene el producto carro, ya que no he implementado aun la lista de producto con la cual voy a realizar el filtro.

Pero quisiera poder extraer la **cantidad** y **especificación** de cada producto sin depender de la "," que los separa y sin tener problemas. Ya que si un usuario por alguna razón no usa las "," o "y-e" para separar un producto de otro no, podría obtener el resultado deseado. **Ejemplo:**

> cuatro camionetas de color rojo cinco carros de maleta compacta  una moto de color rojo ultra rápida.

He estado buscando, pero no encuentro una forma. **Gracias y espero su respuesta.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta a esta pregunta puede ser bastante compleja si no hay un criterio de separación bien definido. Incluso se podría decir que la solución al problema es indefinida, porque los números no tienen fin y el programa no puede contemplar todas las posibilidades. ¿También qué pasaría si la especificación de un producto contiene números? (por ej: cinco tornillos de catorce milímetros)

De cualquier forma, controlando el escenario a unos pocos números de items y suponiendo que todos los productos comienzan con una cantidad en números, se podría hacer alguna aproximación de lo que quieres.
En primer paso, se eliminan todos los separadores innecesarios (e, y, coma) observar que incluí y modifiqué algunos parámetros de los `str_replace`.
Luego se crea un array (`explode`) y se recorre con un `for`. Si se encuentra un elemento que coincida con el array de numeros, pues, es el numero de producto y todo lo demás será la especificación hasta que se encuentre otro elemento numérico.

```
<?php

$num = array('un', 'una', 'dos', 'tres', 'cuatro', 'cinco', 'seis', 
'siete', 'ocho', 'nueve', 'dies', 'once', 'doce', 'trece', 'catorce');

$mess='cuatro camionetas de color rojo, cinco carros de maleta compacta y una moto de color rojo ultra rápida.';
$mess=str_replace(' y ', ' ', $mess);
$mess=str_replace(' e ', ' ', $mess);
$mess=str_replace(', ', ' ', $mess);
$mess=str_replace(',', ' ', $mess);
$mess=str_replace('.', '', $mess);

$array = explode(' ', $mess);

foreach($array as $subString){
    if(in_array(strtolower($subString), $num)) {
        // Si es un numero
        if(isset($cant)) {
            // En la primera vuelta no se entrará en este IF
            echo $cant . ' => ' . $espec . PHP_EOL;
        }
        $cant = $subString;
        $espec = '';
    } else {
        $espec .= $subString . ' ';
    }
}
// El ultimo item no se imprime porque se llega al final del FOR
// Asi que se debe imprimir el último item explicitamente
echo $cant . ' => ' . $espec . PHP_EOL;
```

Salida:

```
cuatro => camionetas de color rojo 
cinco => carros de maleta compacta 
una => moto de color rojo ultra rápida
```

Comment: Su código esta bastante bueno, pero para evitar problemas o usar una gran cantidad de parámetros, ya que como veo el código extrae de acuerdo a la cantidad, y funciona bien, pero se encontraría un problema  al momento en que no se escribiera un numero, es decir, moto super rapida, se sobre entiende que es una sola moto. Voy colocar que cada pedido sea por separado.

Comment: Ademas que también algunos productos pueden tener espacios entre su nombre, ejemplo: Pizza Hawuai, eso imprimirla que funcione correctamente